# How to use useParams in mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I want specific prop from route params and use it to filter data in `redux-store`.

#### Product.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Product = (props) => {
    let { slug } = useParams();
    //console.log(props.match)
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Welcome to <b>{ slug }</b> page</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state, ownProps  ) => {
    // let id = slug;

    return { item: state.items[0]}
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Product);
```

#### App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/:slug">
          <Product/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and whatever links that navigate to `/slug` path are ended up in `Product.js`, Since `Product.js` is being nested nowhere else so i couldn't get specific props pass down but route params. From my perspective this is completely wrong but i couldn't figure out a better way to do it.

Comment: What are the version of your React and Redux library ?

Comment: @ridoansaleh ```"react": "^17.0.1", "redux": "^4.0.5", "react-redux": "^7.2.2"```

Comment: @ridoansaleh In production, i think i should set ```slug``` to something meaningful like item's name instead of id to gain site ranking (SEO). in that case my slug should be name + id + generate random stuffs and finally extract id from route params to use it  filtering data details. Is this what React devs really do in real world situation ?

Comment: yeah, you should name the param relevant to your purpose like productID or productName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the new version of React and Redux. You can try use Hook to get data from redux store.

Better call useSelector instead. Read more [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples)

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Product = () => {
  let { slug } = useParams();

  const item = useSelector((state) => state.items[slug]);

  console.log(item);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        Welcome to <b>{slug}</b> page
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use the `mapDispatchToProps` property which is the second argument of `connect`

`Product.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Product = (props) => {
    const { slug } = useParams();

    const {
       items, // From mapStateToProps
       filterItems // From mapDispatchToProps
    } = props;
    
    const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       setFilteredItems(filterItems(items, slug));
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Welcome to <b>{ slug }</b> page</h3>
            
            <!-- {filteredItems.map(item => { })} -->
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state, ownProps  ) => {
    return { items: state.items}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
      filterItems: (items, filter) => {
         // TODO: Filter logic goes here...

         return items;
      }
   }
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Another performant solution is to use `withRouter`

> You want to access the `state` and `routing params` in one place to select what you want from the state.

One solution to it is using `useParams` inside the component and while you access the state using `connect` it's fine.

However, I once found that this solution causes my component to **re-render a lot** because we don't quietly control how `useParams` being re-invoked, I prefer using the `HOC(higher order component)` that `react-router-dom` offer which is called `withRouter` (**which I found more performant**) and here is how to use it

You wrap it around connect

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

...

export const ArticlePageContainer = withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, undefined)(ArticlePageUI)
);
```

then you can access the `slug` or any `params` from inside the `props` in `mapStateToProps` function

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const slug = props.match.params.slug;
  return {
    targetArticle: state.items.find((item) => item.slug == slug)
  };
}
```

Finally, you use that selected piece of data as in your component, where you get it from the `props` directly now.

```js
function ArticlePageUI(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{"Article Page"}</p>
      <p>{props.targetArticle?.content}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a code sandbox where you can check the implementation yourself
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowhow-to-use-useparams-in-mapstatetoprops-qxxdo?file=/src/article-page.js:87-225

Answer (score -1):

It is so simple, do not use mapDispatchToProps function. Just create a variable and pass useParams into that variable and invoke as a function.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   const title = useParams;
   const { user } = title();
   return {
      card: state.cards.find(card => card.title === user)
   }
}
```

Above example, you can see that I have created a variable named title and pass into useParams and get user param using invoking title function like this title()

Comment: This will throw error (Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component) when mapStateToProps is wrapped in redux connect method which is what this particular user is trying to solve.